# Special assignment in R

Tags: r

My question is just to understand how one feature of the R language works. In "the R language definition" coming with any good release of R, there is something explaining how, for example, the setting of an element of a vector works with something that looks like an assignment but is not so straightforward:

```
x[3:5] <- 13:15
```

is a shortcut for:

```
`*tmp*` <- x
x <- "[<-"(`*tmp*`, 3:5, value=13:15)
rm(`*tmp*`)
```

What I don't understand is the reason why using an intermediate symbol `*tmp*` and not directly do the thing with the setter function.

```
x <- "[<-"(x, 3:5, value=13:15)
```

Until now I was suspecting that it has something to do with garbage collection but as this one has significantlly changed with the v4 and as the documentation did'nt change I am now supecting that I was wrong. Can somebody explain?

Thanks

Comment: No do it again  `x <-  \`[<-\`(x, 3:5, 13:15)`  should definitely work

Comment: Consider nested subset assignment: x[3:5][2] <- 14

Comment: Could confuse the compiler if you use `"` in place of  `.

Comment: @chris. Right, it is a bit dirty. I hope the compiler is able to coerce a string to a symbol. But I just copied what is in the help.start().

Comment: @Onyambu. Sorry it doesn't help : I just copied what is in the documentation. And I am wondering wether there are place not so definitely obvious.

Comment: You mean The code I gave does not work? It works on my computer. I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @Nicolas2 To clarify: *in this particular context*, `"…"` works the same as \`…\`, but it’s (*strongly*, IMHO) discouraged and the syntax only exists for backwards compatibility. The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) says to prefer backticks. The fact that other documentation pages (like the one you quote) use the `"…"` syntax is very unfortunate.

Comment: @Onyambu. The problem is not the code, but WHY it needs a *tmp* , according to the documentation. Is there some cases where we absolutly need this intermediate step?

Comment: It does not a `tmp` I just ran the code without using a `tmp`

Comment: @Onyambu The `*tmp*` variable is *autogenerated* by R when invoking subset assignment or a replacement function. OP’s question is why this variable is necessary. And Roland’s comment further up answers that question.

Comment: @Roland Can you explain? Your example seems to work without the need of *tmp* : v <- 1:10; v <- `[<-`(v,3:5,`[<-`(v[3:5],2,14)); v. But as documentation says, a side effect is that if you have some *tmp* of your own, it is removed.

Comment: I've probably approached this wrong, but `> length(x)
[1] 0
> class(x)
[1] "integer"` and Roland's `> x[3:5][2] <- 14
Tracing `<-`(x[3:5][2], 14) on entry 
Error in .Primitive("<-")(NA_integer_, 14)`, but I don't know `trace` well enough to reveal the autogenerated `*tmp*`. Or clearly, in his example, it isn't autogenerated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, first let's show that the description is quite literal: `` `*tmp*` `` is actually created.

```
`*tmp*` <- NULL
lockBinding("*tmp*", .GlobalEnv)
x[3:5] <- 13:15
#Error: cannot change value of locked binding for '*tmp*'
unlockBinding("*tmp*", .GlobalEnv)
```

Now, the language definition explains that the mechanism is quite general and also used for more complex assignments. Here is an example that actually creates different results if you don't use a `` `*tmp*` `` object:

```
x <- 1:10
local({
  x <- 11:20
  x[3:5] <<- 13:15
})
x
#[1]  1  2 13 14 15  6  7  8  9 10

x <- 1:10
local({
  x <- 11:20
  x <<- `[<-`(x, 3:5, value=13:15)
})
x
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

x <- 1:10
local({
  x <- 11:20
  `*tmp*` <- get("x", envir=parent.env(environment()), inherits=TRUE)
  x <<- `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 3:5, value=13:15)
  rm(`*tmp*`)
})
x
# [1]  1  2 13 14 15  6  7  8  9 10
```

Other examples could probably be found.

Comment: +1, good explanation. But could I convince you *not* to use the legacy pseudo-string syntax, and instead use proper backtick quotes for non-syntactic names? The R documentation itself says using string quotes is discouraged (even though it applies that inconsistently itself).

Comment: It does (clean code is *important*, especially for teaching, and *especially* if the alternative leads to actively confusing code), but you missed four occurrences. ;-)

Comment: No I didn't. `lockBinding` and `unlockBinding` accept symbols or character vectors. I prefer the latter.

Comment: The other two occurrences were copied directly from the language definition.

Comment: Oh, of course agreed for the *Binding functions (didn’t even know they accepted names). The other two is what I meant. :) And yes, the language definition unfortunately uses the legacy notation. Again, I think this is rather unfortunate, and especially teaching material (= Stack Overflow) should take great care to avoid such inconsistencies.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Do I remember correctly that you contributed to the syntax highlighter used by SO? I really wish it would highlight `\`varname\``. There also appears to be a bug (compare `1:10` with `3:5`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph as a side note, as a beginner that didn't really read what was or wasn't discouraged by R, I remember noticing that backticks work mostly the same as string quotes, but only the latter is highlighted by RStudio, hence only for convenience kept using _only_ the string quotes. It's interesting, if the backticks are the _right_ way to do it, why is it still hidden from the syntax highlighters?

Comment: @Roland Yeah, I rewrote the R syntax highligher. Thanks for pointing out the `1:10` bug, that’s a regression (it definitely used to work), I’ll investigate. Identifiers are unfortunately *generally* not highlighted by hljs at the moment. \`foo\` is treated the same as  a regular name. Do you think it should be treated specially?

Comment: @runr I don’t think it’s “hidden”: it’s treated the same as regular names. IMHO that’s the right approach. Further, you say that you “remember noticing that backticks work mostly the same as string quotes”, and unfortunately there are surprising edge cases where this isn’t true, which is precisely why I exhort caution when teaching them: consider `"a" = "b"` and `"a" = b`. Why do these two do different things? Under what circumstances is a quoted string a name and when is it a value? It’s incredibly confusing.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just think the line `x <<- \`[<-\`(\`*tmp*\`, 3:5, value=13:15)` is difficult to read. Somehow my eyes get confused and I focus on `\`(\``.

Comment: @Roland Ah, I agree. Actually a future update of hl.js might alleviate this because apparently it now allows highlighting *operators*, so the `(` in the middle would be coloured differently. Incidentally, how do you use backticks in code inside a comment? the usual Markdown way (double outer backticks) doesn’t work, and the help page doesn’t mention it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `\\`foo\\``

Comment: @Roland FYI, the syntax highlighting of numbers is now [fixed upstream](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/commit/15ed6a45937fbc4e8cb45403e1afe6fbaf2f73ac). And the next version also highlights operators and punctuation so code such as `\`[<-\`(\`*tmp*\`, …` should be more readable (if Stack Overflow highlights operators …).